# before insert trigger, problem with mapping select result to map

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm trying to populate child row's field with parents data, but this apex code goes crazy.

```
trigger before_pod_insert_trigger on pod__c (before insert) {

    Set<String> pp_ids = new Set<String>();

    for (pod__c p:Trigger.New)
        pp_ids.add(p.shipment__c);

    Map<String,Id> sf_ids_map = new Map<String, Id>([SELECT shipment__c, Id from shipment__c where shipment__c in : pp_ids]);

    for(pod__c p : Trigger.New)
    {
        String sf_id = sf_ids_map.get(p.shipment__c);

        if (sf_id == '')
        {
            p.addError('Shipment with pp_id `'+p.shipment__c+'` not found in shipment__c object');            
        }
        else 
        {
            p.shipment_sf_id__c = sf_id;
        }
    }
}
```

Child object is `pod__c` and parent object is `shipment__c`.
with `pod__c.shipment_pp_id__c` field I'm trying to match against `shipment__c.shipment__c`. And that's the trigger code I'm trying for the solution.

The problem is that select statement returns the Shipment__c object itself and can't be mapped to `<String, Id>` list.

Is there any way I can do it simpler or fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not clear how your fields relate, but you can build a map using arbitrary object fields via a loop like this:

```
    Map<String,Id> sf_ids_map = new Map<String, Id>();
    for (shipment__c s : [
            SELECT shipment__c, Id
            from shipment__c
            where shipment__c in : pp_ids
            ]) {
        sf_ids_map.put(s.shipment__c, s.Id);
    }
```

If all the fields are of type `Id` use that type in both the key and value of the  map.

**PS**

Take care when creating a simple map like this that there is one value at most for each key: if there are multiple values later ones will replace earlier ones which may not be what you want. If you want to keep the multiple values, using `Map<Id, Set<Id>>` is one approach, or a more major restructuring of the code might be appropriate.